# Implement custom Iterator and const_iterator for doubly linked list in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, operator-overloading, doubly-linked-list

Here is my implementation of `iterator` and `const_iterator` for Doubly Linked List. Program has mandatory tests. When I am running my program I get error from tests:

> "Decrement operator moves the iterator backward, Prefix", due to a
>   fatal error condition: SIGSEGV - Segmentation violation signal

What am I doing wrong?

**test.cpp  *// here is my test file where I get error //***

```
TEST_CASE("Decrement operator moves the iterator backward", "[stage2]") {
    list l;
    append_to_list(l, { 5.55, 6.66, 7.77, 8.88 });

    auto it = l.end();
    SECTION("Prefix") {
        REQUIRE(*(--it) == 8.88);
        REQUIRE(*(--it) == 7.77);
        REQUIRE(*(--it) == 6.66);
        REQUIRE(*(--it) == 5.55);
        REQUIRE(it == l.begin());
    }

    SECTION("Postfix") {
        it--;
        REQUIRE(*(it--) == 8.88);
        REQUIRE(*(it--) == 7.77);
        REQUIRE(*(it--) == 6.66);
        REQUIRE(*it == 5.55);
        REQUIRE(it == l.begin());
    }
}

TEST_CASE("Decrement operator moves the (const) iterator backward", "[stage2]") {
    list l;
    append_to_list(l, { 5.55, 6.66, 7.77, 8.88 });

    auto it = l.cend();
    SECTION("Prefix") {
        REQUIRE(*(--it) == 8.88);
        REQUIRE(*(--it) == 7.77);
        REQUIRE(*(--it) == 6.66);
        REQUIRE(*(--it) == 5.55);
        REQUIRE(it == l.cbegin());
    }

    SECTION("Postfix") {
        it--;
        REQUIRE(*(it--) == 8.88);
        REQUIRE(*(it--) == 7.77);
        REQUIRE(*(it--) == 6.66);
        REQUIRE(*it == 5.55);
        REQUIRE(it == l.cbegin());
    }
}
```

**list.hpp**

```
class list {
private:
    struct node {
        double val = 0;
        node* prev = nullptr;
        node* next = nullptr;
    };

    node* head = nullptr;
    node* tail = nullptr;
    size_t num_elements = 0;

public:

    class const_iterator {
        node* current_ptr = nullptr;
        const list* o_list = nullptr;
    public:
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
        using value_type = const double;
        using reference = const double&;
        using pointer = const double*;

        const_iterator() = default;
        const_iterator(node* ptr, const list* gen);

        const_iterator& operator++();
        const_iterator operator++(int);
        const_iterator& operator--();
        const_iterator operator--(int);

        reference operator*() const;
        pointer operator->() const;

        bool operator==(const const_iterator& rhs) const;
        bool operator!=(const const_iterator& rhs) const;

        friend class list;
    };

    class iterator {
        node* current_ptr = nullptr;
        const list* o_list = nullptr;
    public:
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
        using value_type = double;
        using reference = double&;
        using pointer = double*;

        iterator() = default;
        iterator(node* ptr, const list* gen);

        iterator& operator++();
        iterator operator++(int);
        iterator& operator--();
        iterator operator--(int);

        reference operator*() const;
        pointer operator->() const;

        operator const_iterator() const;

        bool operator==(const iterator& rhs) const;
        bool operator!=(const iterator& rhs) const;

        friend class list;
    };
```

**list.cpp *// my implementation of iterator and const_iterator //***

```
list::iterator list::begin() {
        return list::iterator(head, this);
    }

    list::iterator list::end() {
        return list::iterator(tail->next, this);
    }

    list::const_iterator list::begin() const {
        return list::const_iterator(head, this);
    }

    list::const_iterator list::end() const {
        return list::const_iterator(tail->next, this);
    }

    list::const_iterator list::cbegin() const {
        return list::const_iterator(head, this);
    }

    list::const_iterator list::cend() const {
        return list::const_iterator(tail->next, this);
    }

    list::iterator::iterator(node *ptr, const list *gen) {
        this->current_ptr = ptr;
        this->o_list = gen;
    }

    list::iterator& list::iterator::operator++() {
        current_ptr = this->current_ptr->next;
        return *this;
    }

    list::iterator& list::iterator::operator--() { //here triggers error!!!
        current_ptr = this->current_ptr->prev;
        return *this;
    }

    list::iterator list::iterator::operator++(int)
    {
        iterator old(*this);
        ++(*this);
        return old;
    }

    list::iterator list::iterator::operator--(int)
    {
        iterator left(*this);
        --(*this);
        return left;
    }
    list::const_iterator& list::const_iterator::operator++() {
        current_ptr = current_ptr->next;
        return *this;
    }

    list::const_iterator& list::const_iterator::operator--() { //here triggers error!!!
        current_ptr = current_ptr->prev;
        return *this;
    }

    list::const_iterator list::const_iterator::operator++(int) {
        const_iterator old = *this;
        ++(*this);
        return old;
    }

    list::const_iterator list::const_iterator::operator--(int) {
        const_iterator old = *(this);
        --(*this);
        return old;
    }
```

Comment: Which line of code is triggering this error?  Do you know?

Comment: @DrewDormann This error triggers on prefix decrement operator of iterator class and const_iterator. (I've commented this error in post)

Comment: It would help, to point to which **line** of the test causes the error to happen and in which **line** of the operator method (not just which method) the error occurs. It may be a dumb question from my side, but where's the "append_to_list" implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using a null `node *` as your end(), which fails to work with operator--; there's no way to decrement it to get at the last node of the list.

You need to use something else as your end sentinel which allows you to get back to the list -- either a fake 'node' on the list that isn't an element of the real list, or add a pointer to the original list to the iterator classes, so when you decrement the end() iterator you can recover the last node in the list.

---

Since your iterator already has an `o_list` pointer, it's easiest just to use that:

```
list::iterator& list::iterator::operator--() {
    current_ptr = current_ptr ? current_ptr->prev : o_list->tail;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: I understood you, but I have no idea how to fix this problem. Can you write solution please?

Comment: Your iterator has a list pointer. Use it to get to get the tail node if the current node is null.